# Tuckey Rewrite: Removing Extension

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using Tuckey to remove the URL .xhtml extension with the following rules:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/?([a-z-]+)/$</from>
    <to>/$1.xhtml</to>
</rule>

<rule>
    <from>^/?([a-z-]+)$</from>
    <to>/$1.xhtml</to>
</rule>
```

So /page/ and /page gets mapped to /page.xthml

However, if I have /directory/page/ this doesn't map to /directory/page.xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule>
    <from>^/?([a-z-/]+)/$</from>
    <to>/$1.xhtml</to>
</rule>

<rule>
    <from>^/?([a-z-/]+)$</from>
    <to>/$1.xhtml</to>
</rule>
```

I added the slash into the list of repeatable characters and this worked

Answer (score 0):

use this rule :

```
<rule>
    <from>^/?[a-z-]*?/?([a-z-]+)/$</from>
    <to>/$1.xhtml</to>
</rule>

<rule>
    <from>^/?[a-z-]*?/?([a-z-]+)$</from>
    <to>/$1.xhtml</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: Why is that better than the answer I have already posted? Also this what if the url is /directory/directory/page?

Comment: it will allow zero or more times I know, yours will allow zero or one times, let the OP decide whats suitable for him :)